# Multi-model RSS Feed in Django

Tags: python, django, rss

I am trying to figure out how to have a multi-model RSS feed in Django. That is, I would like Django to serve updates of two different models under one RSS url.

Here is what I have thus far

```
class ArticleFeed(Feed):
    title = "Articles"
    link = "/articles/"
    description = "RSS feed of Articles"
 
    def items(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(is_published=1)
 
    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title
       
    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.get_description()
 
    def item_link(self, item):
        return item.get_absolute_url()

class VideoFeed(Feed):
    pass
 
class atomFeed(Feed):
    feed_type = Atom1Feed
```

In urls.py I have the following path

```
path('rss/', ArticleFeed(), name="article_feed"),
```

I would like `rss/` to provide updates to both the Article and Video model. The Video model has similar fields but is non-verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

you can use queryset3 = queryset1.union(queryset2) to concatenate items of two different models and use this in feed.items(self):

```
def items(self):
    query1 = Article1.objects.filter(is_published=1)
    query2 = Article2.objects.filter(is_published=1)

    query = query1.union(query2)

    # do any sorting AFTER union
    query_sorted = query.order_by('a_field', 'another_field')   

    self.item_count = query_sorted.count()
  
    return query_sorted
```

union() works as long as queries have the same fields.

If you have different field names but same content like "name" and "item_name" then you can rename the field in one of the queries:

```
    query2 = Article2.objects.filter(is_published=1).annotate(name=F('item_name')).values('name')
```

note: above is "pseudo" code - I did not run it so it might have syntax errors

Comment: What if queries do not have the same exact fields? They are the same in meaning but not in name.

Comment: with .values('a_field', 'another_field') you can choose the fields that are included in the query so that they are same. As you need only the fields that are necessary to create the feed (e.g. name or url of a mp3 file ..). If the fields have teh same content but are named differently in the model, you can use .annotate(field_name=F('org_field_name')) to rename them. I have edited the answer above

Comment: I have have not tried union with queries that have different fields, so I do not know if the result is a error message or other behaviour